# SpringBoot + DAPR + Solace (username, password) not working

Tags: spring-boot, vpn, publish-subscribe, solace, dapr

**#1**
Solace PubSub Standard ran via Docker.
SpringBoot app has a REST endpoint that calls DaprClient to publish event. Ran `dapr run` without any errors.

Invoked the REST endpoint. No errors. However, the messages were not published.
The receive application of the Solace admin also not receiving any messages.

Also, tried shutting down the Solace.
Invoked the REST endpoint. No errors. I would have expected an error here because Solace is not running.

**#2**
Also, what is the metadata to configure VPN name?
used this as reference: https://docs.dapr.io/reference/components-reference/supported-pubsub/setup-solace-amqp/

Tried using the same credentials using the Java publisher/subscriber worked - with/without VPN.

Please help. Thank you!

Messages should be published when Solace is running.
Error should be thrown from DaprClient when Solace is not running.

Comment: The default message vpn name is "default" if you just started up a local broker. I'm not familiar enough with the use of dapr to answer the rest of your question but will ping someone else. Did you configure it to publish to a Solace topic? Something like `client.pubsub.publish(PUBSUB_NAME, “topic:retail/orders”, {“orderId”: 123});
` from this blog: https://solace.com/blog/dapr-pubsub-event-broker/

Answer (score 1):

The AMQP connection to Solace does not require a VPN name. Simply put in the host name and credentials and it should work. There should be an error on your DAPR server when there is a disconnect event.

Comment: thank you for your response. however, when the strategy requires us to use VPN, does the DAPR Solace pubsub has any configuration for VPN?

Comment: Since the DAPR Solace PubSub+ Plugin works over the AMQP protocol, a VPN configuration will never be needed. If you are using multiple message VPNs, each VPN would have a separate AMQP port.